# Override @media style using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to save to pdf some pages of a screened web site from Mozilla FF. However I've stumbled upon a site with css protection that prevents print (and so print to pdf): it prints blank page.
I need pure JavaScript, that when run from the js console to override any
@media print styles. I tried few commands but without success. I know how to do it manually but need easier way.

The css stylesheet is

```
* {-moz-user-select: none;-khtml-user-select: none;-webkit-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;-o-user-select: none;user-select: none;}
@media print {html, body {display: none;}}
```

PS. It would be nice for the text select prevention too, but not that important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to override the CSS by injecting `<style>` into `<head>` like this:

```
var override = document.createElement("style");
override.innerText = "* {user-select: auto;} @media print {html, body {  display: block; }}";
document.head.appendChild(override);
```

[Example on Codepen](https://codepen.io/helb/pen/pexggv) (try the print preview with and without JS)

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I needed.
My fault was that I've searched for direct property to set on some object...